# Incompatible Jackson version: 2.10.2 on trying to create Rdd of Row in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I tried to create RDD using sc.parallelize. It gave an exception as :

```
   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.withScope(SparkContext.scala:701)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.parallelize(SparkContext.scala:718)
    at df_avro.SampleDf$.main(SampleDf.scala:25)
    at df_avro.SampleDf.main(SampleDf.scala)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Incompatible Jackson version: 2.10.2
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$class.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:64)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule.setupModule(DefaultScalaModule.scala:19)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:808)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<init>(RDDOperationScope.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.<clinit>(RDDOperationScope.scala)
    ... 4 more
```

This was the code :

```
 val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setMaster("local[2]")
  .setAppName("TheApp")
val spark = SparkSession.builder()
  .config(conf)
  .getOrCreate()

val sc = spark.sparkContext

val rowArray: Array[Row] = Array(
  Row(1,"hello", true),
  Row(2,"goodbye", false)
)

val rows: RDD[Row] = sc.parallelize(rowArray)

println(rows.count())
```

Why is this causing an exception. Am I missing something ?

Dependencies used :

```
    val spark2Version ="2.2.1"

// additional libraries
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % spark2Version,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % spark2Version,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % spark2Version )
```

Comment: scala version ?

Comment: scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

Comment: is this issue fixed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can add below dependency overrides inside your build.sbt & try again.

```
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.6.5"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.6.5"
dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.11" % "2.6.5"
```

Comment: It solved the issue, could you please explain why and how ?

Comment: some of your dependencies are conflicting or using higher version of jackson libraries. but spark 2.2 version needs jackson 2.6.5 version.

Answer (score 0):

u can go to

```
at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.JacksonModule$class.setupModule(JacksonModule.scala:64)
```

and see

```
  def setupModule(context: SetupContext) {
    val MajorVersion = version.getMajorVersion
    val MinorVersion = version.getMinorVersion
    context.getMapperVersion match {
      case version@VersionExtractor(MajorVersion, minor) if minor < MinorVersion =>
        throw new JsonMappingException("Jackson version is too old " + version)
      case version@VersionExtractor(MajorVersion, minor) =>
        // Under semantic versioning, this check would not be needed; however Jackson
        // occasionally has functionally breaking changes across minor versions
        // (2.4 -> 2.5 as an example). This may be the fault of the Scala module
        // depending on implementation details, so for now we'll just declare ourselves
        // as incompatible and move on.
        if (minor > MinorVersion) {
          throw new JsonMappingException("Incompatible Jackson version: " + version)
        }
      case version =>
        throw new JsonMappingException("Incompatible Jackson version: " + version)
    }
```

so it's clearly;u use a higher version than this;u can see the jar's version;
So changing your dependency's version can solve it;

I use 2.11 scala,2.4.1 spark,3.1.4 hadoop;
Then I use

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version> 2.6.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version> 2.6.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version> 2.6.7</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

You can use this code to modify your pom.xml file. Specify the version u want in pace of 2.6.7 and build your code again. This configuration is for Maven. It will help in resolving the issue of jackson version mismatch.